# Titanium Accelerator - How to output the result of a function

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

i have the following code for rolling a dice.

```
function rollDice(){
  var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var diceTotal = die1 + die2;
}
```

i am wanting this function to execute when a button is pressed so i have this.

```
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    rollDice();
});
```

so how do i display the results of die1,die2 and diceTotal currently i have return in just because it's what im used to using to displaying the result.

Comment: Last sentence is very hard to understand. Could you rephrase that sentence?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access dice1, dice2, diceTotal   outside the function rollDice(), you can define variable outside rollDice() (see below). After doing that, you can access that variable in  any part of same js file.

```
var dice1, dice2, diceTotal;
function rollDice(){
   dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   diceTotal = dice1 + dice2;
}
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    rollDice();
    alert( 'dice1=' + dice1 + '   dice2=' + dice2 + '   diceTotal=' + diceTotal);  
}
```